# Pure JavaScript JSON compare array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, find

I have to compare some JSON data and return index of position. I use pure JavaScript.

I have data below:

```
 NAMES
 [
    {
      "someName" : Name1,
      "secondData" : "aaaa1",
      "thirdData" : bbbb1
    },
    {
      "someName" : Name2,
      "secondData" : "aaaa2",
      "thirdData" : bbbb2
    },
    {
      "someName" : Name3,
      "secondData" : "aaaa3",
      "thirdData" : bbbb3
    },
        {
      "someName" : Name4,
      "secondData" : "aaaa4",
      "thirdData" : bbbb4
    }
]
```

and JSON SEATS

```
[
  {
    "seats" : 0,
    "someName" : "Name4",
    omeData" : null,
    "someData" : null
  },
  {
    "seats" : 1,
    "someName" : "Name3",
    "someData" : null,
    "someData" : null
  },
  {
    "seats" : 2,
    "someName" : "Name1",
    "someData" : null,
    "someData" : null
  },    
  {
    "seats" : 3,
    "someName" : "Name2",
    "someData" : null,
    "someData" : null
  }
]
```

All what I want to do is compare this JSON like this:

```
Take someName from NAMES.someName and search the same name in SEATS.someName if is the same create new array RESULTS. Index in RESULTS array shuldbe SEATS.seats and data from NAMES.
```

Example below

```
RESULTS[0] = NAMES[{"someName" : Name4,"secondData" : "aaaa4","thirdData" : bbbb4}] 
RESULTS[1] = NAMES[{"someName" : Name3,"secondData" : "aaaa3","thirdData" : bbbb3}] 
RESULTS[2] = NAMES[{"someName" : Name1,"secondData" : "aaaa1","thirdData" : bbbb1}] 
RESULTS[3] = NAMES[{"someName" : Name2,"secondData" : "aaaa2","thirdData" : bbbb2}]
```

I start do this like this but I stack

```
for(i=0;i<=459; i++) {
  if(mergeData[i][2] == jsonData[4].rows[i].find(compareElement)) {
  }
}
function compareElement(element) {
  return element.someName == i;
}
```

Problem is if I use find like this I have some error and program stop I can't find way how to solve this.

Comment: If the index of the new array is taken from an arbitrary object property, you could end up with a sparse array. Is that ok with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = [];

NAMES.forEach(function(name) {
  var found = SEATS.find(function(seat) {
    return name.someName === seat.someName
  });

  if (found) {
    result[found.seats] = name;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Work perfect !

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for both Objects as well as Arrays.

```
function compare(obj: any, obj2: any): boolean {
  if (typeof obj !== typeof obj2) {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj2 !== "object") {
    return obj === obj2;
  } else {
    for (let key in obj) {
      if (key) {
        return compare(obj[key], obj2[key]);
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```